# What is a Lower Penthouse?

Tags: real-estate

I recently saw a Real Estate listing which curiously boasted that the unit was

*A lovely and spacious lower penthouse*

I always thought a penthouse meant the top floor, therefore one penthouse floor per building. What is a lower penthouse?

Answer (score 2):

A penthouse is an apartment built upon what would otherwise be the roof,!typically will some patio/garden space around it.

Some buildings have more than one roof, at different levels.